# Is there a parse_str + http_build_query alternative that handles duplicate keys?

Tags: php, parsing

I have the following code

```
$post = 'foo=bar&foo=baz';
parse_str($post, $parameters);
```

Yields:

```
array(1) {
   'foo' =>
   string(3) "baz"
}
```

I cannot modify `$post`.

What I am looking for is a version of `parse_str` (handling edge cases and decoding as parse_str does), but allowing duplicate keys.

It should be compatible with `http_build_query` to reassemble the `$post` data (after modification).

Did anybody implement such a method yet or is there a lib for it?

My searches did not yield one yet.

Comment: Why not make one that does what you specifically need?

Comment: `$post = str_replace('foo=', 'foo[]=', $post);` SCNR

Comment: `http://php.net/manual/ru/function.parse-str.php#76792`

Comment: @splash58 Yes, thank you! Since stackoverflow exists I stopped reading the PHP doc comments. The only question is how to assemble it back to the original query str. http_build_query inserts foo[0] foo[1] ...

Comment: The `\GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Query` class seems to be a much better alternative to `parse_str()` and `http_build_query()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on http://php.net/manual/ru/function.parse-str.php#76792 I decided to to my processing inline - without converting the whole think to some structure and building it back. That is what I ended up with:

```
function process_query_str($str) {
    # result array
    $parts = array();

    # split on outer delimiter
    $pairs = explode('&', $str);

    # loop through each pair
    foreach ($pairs as $i) {
        # split into name and value
        list($name,$value) = explode('=', $i, 2);
        $value = urldecode($value);

        // **** DO PROCESSING ****
        $value = strtoupper($value);

        // reassemble
        $parts[] = http_build_query(array($name=>$value));
    }

    # return result array
    return implode('&', $parts);
}

$query = process_query_str('foo=bar&foo=baz');
echo $query;
```

Comment: I do not recommend this approach, or any other technique that deliberately makes a query string with duplicated keys.

Comment: @mickmackusa Sure, I am also not a fan of such duplicate keys (especially as PHP ignores them), but some systems seem to require and process them